# Calling a Python function for each page in an atlas

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I have made a script to do some calculations for each page of a QGIS atlas ([QGIS Atlas with insert map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317317/qgis-atlas-with-insert-map/317734))

The script is adjusting the bounding box of a map on the layout page. To make it run for each page, I have made a textbox where the script is returning nothing. I do not care for the return value, I just want the side effect of having the bounding box adjusted.  The solution is working nicely, but it feels a bit kludgy.

Is there anywhere else I could put the script to make it run once per page for my atlas?

(using qgis 3.6.1 on windows 10)

*Correction:* When testing a bit more, it turns out some maps are being exported before they have finished rendering (I am fetching some relatively large data sets from a wms-server). When I browse manually through the maps, it goes a little slow, but when I export the entire atlas, for about  one third of the maps, the map I am adjusting manually is showing the map from the former page.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is quite old, there is still no direct solution for the Qt timing problems that occur in QGIS when adding content via scripts or rendering HTML/Javascript during Atlas generation.

But we can work around the problem with a small Python Expression function:

```
from qgis.core import qgsfunction
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QTimer,QEventLoop
@qgsfunction(args=1, group='Custom', usesgeometry=False)
def waitX(values, feature, parent):
    loop = QEventLoop()
    QTimer.singleShot(int(values[0]),loop.quit)
    loop.exec_()
    return 0
```

The purpose of this function is to interrupt QGIS for a few milliseconds without interfering with the background process. It returns value 0 because I normally put it inside the rendering settings of the layout map item:

[image]

[image]